# C#からのExcelVBA実行と、ExcelからVBAを直接実行した場合の処理時間について

Tags: c#, vba, excel

ExcelのVBAをC#で実行しようと考えています。
現状、ExcelからボタンクリックでVBAを実行すると1時間かかる処理が、C#側から「Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel」を使って

`xlApp.Run("Sheet1.Btn_Calc_Click");`

で同じマクロを実行すると3時間かかってしまします。

Interop.ExcelでExcel処理を行うと遅いというのは聞きますが、Excel側のマクロ実行にも影響するものでしょうか。

原因や、処理速度の短縮方法がありましたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 0):

これが原因なのかわからないため、的外れな回答かもしれませんが、

`Main`メソッドに対し[`[STAThread]`属性](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)は指定されていますでしょうか？ 指定されていない場合、スレッドは`マルチスレッドアパートメント`として初期化されます。
マルチスレッドアパートメントからシングルスレッドアパートメントのオブジェクトを操作する場合、マーシャリングが必要となり、それによって処理が遅延しているのかもしれません。

コメントによると既に`[STAThread]`を指定していたとのことですが、呼び出し元のC#プログラムはコンソールアプリケーションでしょうか？ [シングルスレッドアパートメントの要件](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/single-threaded-apartments)としてGUIなどのメッセージループを回す必要があります。
`[STAThread]`を外す、別スレッドで実行するなどの方法でマルチスレッドアパートメントで実行したり、`[STAThread]`を付けシングルスレッドアパートメントのまま何らかの方法でメッセージループを回したりすることで、改善されないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。Mainにて[STAThread]の定義はされていました。